# How to hatch eggs at home without a bulb-based incubator?

Tags: home, animals

I came across some videos on YouTube where they used a home-made incubator to hatch hen eggs. The system was nothing fancy:

- A cardboard box with a light inside
- Some aluminum foil near the bulb (perhaps to reflect the light).
- A glass of water inside (they claimed it was to increase the humidity).
- Saw dust or dried grass over which they put the eggs.

The process they used was to:

- Keep the light on 24 hours, 21 days. Suggested power of bulb is 25 watts.
- Rotate the eggs twice a day.

Another variant used sunlight during the day. They didn't put the container directly under sunlight but outside the house where it is warm enough for incubation.

I am quite interested to replicate the process. However, winter is near in my country (India) and I stay in a place where it rains often. So, I can't rely on the sun always. Also, I don't want to light the bulb for 21 days.

How should I incubate the eggs?

I have read the optimal incubation conditions for chicken eggs. The temperature needed is between 98-102 degree Fahrenheit. And humidity needed is 50-65%.

I haven't tried but I think I will be able to increase the temperature by using wool or dry grass. Humidity in my place is higher than the required value, I am unsure how to control it.

I would appreciate any advice regarding this.

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to sustainable living.  There seems to be ample information about optimal incubator conditions available online.  Did you look for it and have trouble finding it?  Was it unclear?

Comment: Thank you Jean Paul Calderone for the comment. I will look for the optimal conditions and update my question soon.